# Edit hovertemplate with plotly

Tags: plotly

The porpuse is to **add data to hovertemplate**. I want to add z=y1+y2=[3,3,7]. I have tried many ways but it doesn't work, even thougth it look similar to other questions it is not because of how the figure is done.

```
import plotly.express as px

fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "bananas"]
y1=[1,2,3]
y2=[2,1,4]

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name = 'J1', x = fruits, y = y1, 
           text = y1, textposition = 'outside'),
    go.Bar(name = 'J2', x = fruits, y =y2, 
           text = y2, textposition = 'outside')])

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="<br>".join([
                "Fruit: %{x}",
                "Cuantity: %{y}",
                "Porcentaje mortalidad: %{z}"
    ]))

fig.show()
```

[fig.show() display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4CUP.png)

You can copy the code and try yourself, how to **display a value in z** ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- have used *customdata* as this is accessible in *hovertemplate*
- full code below

```
import plotly.express as px

fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "bananas"]
y1=[1,2,3]
y2=[2,1,4]
z = [x+y for x,y in zip(y1,y2)]

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name = 'J1', x = fruits, y = y1, customdata=z,
           text = y1, textposition = 'outside'),
    go.Bar(name = 'J2', x = fruits, y =y2, customdata=z,
           text = y2, textposition = 'outside')])

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate="<br>".join([
                "Fruit: %{x}",
                "Cuantity: %{y}",
                "Porcentaje mortalidad: %{customdata}"
    ]))

fig.show()
```